# Can make jQuery 100% width whilst keeping animation

Tags: jquery, width

I'm having issues with a slideshow which isn't working as I'd like.

Basically I have two images which I need to be the full page width (100%). Then when the browser is re-sized/shrunk I need them to stay in the centre/top of the div but the edges get cropped off.

I have managed to get this to work with the 1st div tag but as soon as it animated the resize ability stops and I simply get a horizontal scroll bar.

Any ideas? Im stuck!

```
#animatedbannerkitchen {
    float: left;
    height: 381px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.slideshow {
    float: left;
    height: 381px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#bannerone {
    background-image: url(purchase-tableware.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 381px;
    background-size: cover; 
}
#bannertwo {
    background-image: url(tasty-plate.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 381px;
    background-size: cover; 
}






 <!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.2.74.js"></script>

<!--  initialize the slideshow when the DOM is ready scrollLeft -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 1500,
         slideResize: false,
        timeout: 7000// choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
</script>
```

and finally the body content

```
<div id="animatedbannerkitchen">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <div id="bannerone"></div>
    <div id="bannertwo"></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: if i remove the slidshow div both banner1+2 resize perfectly but dont animate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).onLoad(function() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  $('#bannerone').css('background-width', windowWidth);
  $('#bannertwo').css('background-width', windowWidth);
});
```

Or

```
$(window).onLoad(function() {
  var bannerOneWidth= $('#bannerone').width();
  $('#bannerone').css('background-width', bannerOneWidth);
  var bannerTwoWidth= $('#bannertwo').width();
  $('#bannertwo').css('background-width', bannerTwoWidth);
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help but I added this to the jquery but it doesnt seem to work. Slideshow banner two wont fit 100% when window is resized